# LaunchScreen IOS Xamarin Forms Not Showing

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, launch-screen

I followed some tutorials on how to display my launch screen on ios. but it is still not showing. what I am missing?. All I see is the default blue screen.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos

This is what I have 
[image: on the launch screen.stroyboard]

2. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is enough to change the `LaunchScreen` of a Xamarin.iOS app. The steps are:

1.Create a new `LaunchScreen1.Storyboard` and add your `custom view` there.

2.Change the `Launch Screen option` in `info.plist` as you did in the screenshot in the question.

I would suggest you to clean and rebuild your project, and then run it again. Also you can try to uninstall the app in your simulator first and then run your new project.

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/launch-screen-iOS) and you can check it.