# Xamarin.Forms iOS storyboard not showing, even after being built and set in the Info.plist file

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, storyboard

Titles says it all - I've been able to connect a Mac to Xamarin.Forms app so I can use the iOS Designer to (successfully) build the LaunchScreen.storyboard file; but even after setting it to the Launch Screen in the Visual Assets of the Info.plist file, it still has the base Xamarin launch screen (the one with the light blue background and X icon).

This is being tested on an old iPhone 6S.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Config the LaunchScreen.storyboard in the info.plist, make sure the name is same as your file name:

[image]

2. Close your visual-studio. Delete the `bin/obj` folder in both Xamarin.forms project and Xamarin.iOS project.

[image]

[image]

3. Uninstall the app in your  old iPhone 6S.
4. Reopen your project, clean and rebuild, then install your app again.

Comment: Thanks, so that worked on the Simulator; but not on my iPhone. Any ideas? Can I just make it a .xib or it will it get denied to be on the store?

Comment: EDIT - Neither a .xib or a storyboard works on my physical device unfortunately.

Comment: What's the iOS version of your real device?

Comment: Can you please try the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60843779/10539446)?

Comment: iOS is up to date as much as Apple will allow it - 12.5 as of a few days ago. The storyboard is showing perfectly fine on all of my simulators; but will not show up on the physical iPhone 6S (neither will the AppIcons). I've even fully Reset the phone just to make sure it wasn't Springboard caching these items.

Comment: Well, it's really hard to say where is the problem as it should work if you followed all steps in the doc. Do you have another real device to test?